# How to implement a Typescript interface that allows additional properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Ok, I have been struggling with this one as all information I find is about how to define interfaces that allow other properties, but not how to create a class that can implement the interface.

I have (or want to have) the following interface:

```js
export interface IEnvironment {
    value: string;
    names: string[];
    [x: string | 'value' | 'names']: (() => boolean) | string | string[]
};
```

Then I want a class that implements said interface, but I only want to implement the `value` and `names` properties.

For full disclosure, I want to create an environment object with `value`, `names` and one function per name in `names`.  Like this:

```js
export class Environment implements IEnvironment {
    value: string;
    names: Array<string>;
    static defaultNames: string[] = ['Development', 'PreProduction', 'Production'];
    constructor(value: string, names?: Array<string>) {
        this.value = value;
        this.names = names ?? Environment.defaultNames;
        let currEnvFound = false;
        this.names.forEach((name) => {
            // Look at all the hoops I had to jump so TypeScript would not complain.  Suggestions welcome.
            (this as unknown as { [x: string]: () => boolean })[`is${name}`] = function () { return (this as unknown as Environment).value === name; };
            currEnvFound = currEnvFound || name === value;
        });
        // Throw if the current environment value was not found.
        if (!currEnvFound) {
            throw new Error(`The provided environment value "${value}" was not found among the provided list of environments.`);
        }
    }
};
```

Now this works except for one error I get:

> Class 'Environment' incorrectly implements interface 'IEnvironment'.
> Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Environment'.

So how can I do this?  I'm a noob in the TypeScript arena, so I'd rather ask the experts.

If no solution, could this be worked around with another interface that extends `IEnvironment`?  Like remove the extra properties thing and move it to another interface that I would use as consumer of the object so I get the correct Intellisense.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to declare this dynamic x property from interface as class property.

Add this line as your class property: `[x: string]: string|(() => boolean)|string[];`

Finally, your class looks like this:

```
class Environment implements IEnvironment {
    value: string;
    names: Array<string>;
    static defaultNames: string[] = ['Development', 'PreProduction', 'Production'];

    //ADD THIS
    [x: string]: string|(() => boolean)|string[];

    constructor(value: string, names?: Array<string>) {
        this.value = value;
        this.names = names ?? Environment.defaultNames;
        
        let currEnvFound = false;
        this.names.forEach((name) => {
            // Look at all the hoops I had to jump so TypeScript would not complain.  Suggestions welcome.
            (this as unknown as { [x: string]: () => boolean })[`is${name}`] = function () { return (this as unknown as Environment).value === name; };
            currEnvFound = currEnvFound || name === value;
        });
        // Throw if the current environment value was not found.
        if (!currEnvFound) {
            throw new Error(`The provided environment value "${value}" was not found among the provided list of environments.`);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark question as solved.